# Could not set unknown property 'artifactType' for extension 'firebaseAppDistribution'

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to configure my build.gradle file to upload a bundle to the firebase distribution, I'm following these [instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-gradle?apptype=aab#step_3_configure_your_distribution_properties) but when I add this statement(artifactType="AAB") inside the block firebaseAppDistribution to get a bundle file I got this error:

***Could not set unknown property 'artifactType' for extension 'firebaseAppDistribution' of type com.google.firebase.appdistribution.gradle.AppDistributionExtension.***

This is the code on the build.gradle:

```
firebaseAppDistribution {
        artifactType="AAB"
        serviceCredentialsFile = System.getenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS")
        groups = System.getenv("ANDROID_RELEASE")
      }
```

What could be the problem? I know firebase just added support for uploading bundle format files to the app distribution, I already liked the accounts for firebase and the play store, so I'm a little bit lost because this is the first time I try to do this and this feature is pretty on firebase distribution.

These are my dependencies:

- classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
- distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
- classpath "com.google.firebase:firebase-appdistribution-gradle:2.0.1"